# how to parsing in python list type from request

Tags: python

I would like to use the bitcoin api. The received data is below:

```
[
  {
    'market': 'KRW-BTC',
    'candle_date_time_utc': '2020-05-04T03:17:00',
    'candle_date_time_kst': '2020-05-04T12:17:00',
    'opening_price': 10662000.0,
    'high_price': 10676000.0,
    'low_price': 10662000.0,
    'trade_price': 10675000.0,
    'timestamp': 1588562256134,
    'candle_acc_trade_price': 18269778.31894,
    'candle_acc_trade_volume': 1.71334319,
    'unit': 1
  }
]
```

This is only one list type data.

I would like to parse this data below:

`['market' : "KRW-BTC" , 'candle_date_time_utc': '2020-05-04T03:17:00' ~~~ ]`

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean parse? Do you want to access the values in market and candle_date_time_utc?   Is this returned as a string or a list of dictionaries as above? Did you attempt anything so far? Can you share the code?

Comment: The list you want as outcome is not valid. `{'market': 'KRW-BTC', 'candle_date_time': '2020-05-04',}` is. Do you mean you want to extract the dictionary from the received list?

Comment: What have you tried ? Where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

This how to access a value in a list of dictionaries.

```
r = [{'market': 'KRW-BTC', 'candle_date_time_utc': '2020-05-04T03:17:00', 'candle_date_time_kst': '2020-05-04T12:17:00', 'opening_price': 10662000.0, 'high_price': 10676000.0, 'low_price': 10662000.0, 'trade_price': 10675000.0, 'timestamp': 1588562256134, 'candle_acc_trade_price': 18269778.31894, 'candle_acc_trade_volume': 1.71334319, 'unit': 1}]
# r < this is the list  [0] < the index of the dictionary in the list 'market' the key to the value you'd like to extract
print (r[0]['market'])
print (r[0]['candle_date_time_utc'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list.

```
list =[{'market': 'KRW-BTC', 'candle_date_time_utc': '2020-05-04T03:17:00', 'candle_date_time_kst': '2020-05-04T12:17:00', 'opening_price': 10662000.0, 'high_price': 10676000.0, 'low_price': 10662000.0, 'trade_price': 10675000.0, 'timestamp': 1588562256134, 'candle_acc_trade_price': 18269778.31894, 'candle_acc_trade_volume': 1.71334319, 'unit': 1}]
for obj in list:
    print(obj['market'])
```